WKWebView scrollview wider than webView
I'm having an issue where my webpage is adding plain white space on the right side of the page causing a horizontal scroll, but only when loaded in a WKWebView in iOS. Not when loaded in Safari in iOS
The webpage is responsive:
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    /* Adjust the breakpoint (768px) based on your needs */
    
    .tile-container {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    
      .super-tile {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
  
    .arrow {
      display: none;
    }
  }

And it has the meta tag:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

WKWebView is configured:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsHandler")
    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "errorHandler")
    webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "pickerHandler")
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.isInspectable = true
    webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webView.configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = false
    
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!))
}

No elements report wider than the screen size. However document.documentElement.scrollWidth reports 540 (device width 393):
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollWidth") { (result, error) in
            if let width = result as? CGFloat {
                print("HTML Content Width: \(width)")
            }
        }
    }

The WKWebView is instantiated from Interface Builder. It doesn't have the same problem with https://nytimes.com instead of the desired webpage
This is running on an iPhone 15 Pro simulator as I do not have a physical iPhone to try. No issue running on physical iPad or through Catalyst
Any ideas?

Turns out the simulator cached a CSS file that kept the width at 540 after it had been changed
Operator error
